# What is the difference between the graphs of $z=xy$ and $z=x^2-y^2$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, 3d

> What is the difference between the shape of the graphs of $z=xy$ and $z=x^2-y^2$?

Are they different or just rotated? Kind of hard to confirm, because I know you can transform them.

But I don't know how or how to show that one is the transformation (rotation) of the other.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=x+y, v=x-y$.  Then $z=uv$.  So one graph is simply a rotation of the other, magnified by $2$ (to normalize $u$ and $v$).

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: Thanks.  The poster's reference to knowledge that one curve can be transformed to another, together with the tags indicating relative inexperience, persuaded me that some work had been done before posting.  Upon reflection, this suggests a potential issue to me.  Users seeking help at this level seem to me more likely to post questions that do them an injustice by failing to reflect the work they have already done on the problem.  They won't be used to writing mathematics at all and their inexperience at writing proofs make it more likely they won't bother writing up their blind alleys.

Comment: That's why it's more important to engage with the user, before answering, to help them make the most of what they do know, and where they are stuck, before answering.  I trust your intuition, and I have not known you to run after the poorest of posts to rack up rep.  I did not post the comment to personally address you; just trying to get the word out.  We want to give users the chance to add more to their question, that they may know, but are timid about possibly being wrong.

Comment: I took the post in the spirit in which you intended it and read the linked Meta announcement.  I do think when making closure/removal decisions it's important to cut the mathematically inexperienced a little more slack.

Comment: It's your job, as a potential answerer, to assist the asker, via suggestions, links, etc. learn about the sites expectation, suggesting ways the OP can improve their question... and *waiting to answer until they have improved their question.*  If you forever "cut an asker slack, they will never grow, never learn the expectations of this site.  You can bring a user a fish every day, your years, to ensure they eat, or you can teach a user to fish.

Comment: If you don't have the time to help the askers I agree need mentoring, then just don't answer, and allow someone who truly cares about their education on this site, and their academic success help, and they hint or answer once the asker pitches in.  You are doing no favors by handing out solutions to homework questions.

Comment: I'm the OP and just to clarify, it wasn't a homework question. I'm taking vector calculus and am aware of transformations and linear transformations, but not beyond knowing they exist and vaguely knowing they relate to matrix multiplication... Sorry if I should have put more work into figuring it out myself. Can you give me some suggestions for posting next time so that I don't violate community guidelines? Thank you for caring about others' mathematical education, I really appreciate people like you.

Comment: @Eitan_Yosef Mostly show your work.  If the background you put in your comment had been in your question, this would have been a non-issue.